# Assertion error on a unit Django TestCase

Tags: python, django-tests

I created a unit test for my `Question.save()` method in my webapp and when I run `python manage.py test` I get an Assertion error as follows described below?

Here is my part of `test.py`:

```
def test_elasticsearch_upsert_on_save(self, ElasticsearchMock):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
                username = 'unittest',
                password='unittest',
                )
        question_title = 'Unit test'
        question_body = 'some long text'
        q = Question(
                title=question_title,
                question=question_body,
                user=user,
                )
        q.save()

        self.assertIsNotNone(q.id)
        self.assertTrue(ElasticsearchMock.called)
        mock_client = ElasticsearchMock.return_value
        mock_client.update.assert_called_once_with(
            settings.ES_INDEX,
            id=q.id,

            body={
                'doc': {
                    '_type': 'doc',
                    'text':'{}\n{}'.format(question_title, question_body),
                    'question_body':question_body,
                    'title': question_title,
                    'id': q.id,
                    'created': q.created,
                },'doc_as_upsert': True,
            }
        )
```

part of models.py:

```
    def as_elasticsearch_dict(self):
        return {
        '_id': self.id,
        '_type': 'doc',
        'text': '{}\n{}'.format(self.title, self.question),
        'question_body': self.question,
        'title': self.title,
        'id': self.id,
        'created': self.created,
        }

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):


        super().save(force_insert=force_insert,
                    force_update=force_update,
                    using=using,
                    update_fields=update_fields)
        elasticsearch.upsert(self)
```

I expect the test to pass but I get the following error:

```
FAIL: test_elasticsearch_upsert_on_save (qanda.tests.QuestionSaveTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1204, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "C:\Users\tafapc1\answerly\django\qanda\tests.py", line 48, in test_elasticsearch_upsert_on_save
    },'doc_as_upsert': True,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 840, in assert_called_once_with
    return self.assert_called_with(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 829, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: Expected call: update('answerly', body={'doc': {'_type': 'doc', 'text': 'Unit test\nsome long t
ext', 'question_body': 'some long text', 'title': 'Unit test', 'id': 1, 'created': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 1
1, 19, 38, 37, 498420, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 'doc_as_upsert': True}, id=1)
Actual call: update('answerly', 'doc', body={'doc': {'_type': 'doc', 'text': 'Unit test\nsome long text', 'ques
tion_body': 'some long text', 'title': 'Unit test', 'id': 1, 'created': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 11, 19, 38,
37, 498420, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 'doc_as_upsert': True}, id=1)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.420s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the expected and the actual call below each other, you can see that they are actually different, so it makes sense that your test fails.

```
expected=update('answerly',        body={'doc': {'_type': 'doc', 'text': 'Unit test\nsome long text', 'question_body': 'some long text', 'title': 'Unit test', 'id': 1, 'created': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 11, 19, 38, 37, 498420, tzinfo=)}, 'doc_as_upsert': True}, id=1)

actual=  update('answerly', 'doc', body={'doc': {'_type': 'doc', 'text': 'Unit test\nsome long text', 'question_body': 'some long text', 'title': 'Unit test', 'id': 1, 'created': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 11, 19, 38, 37, 498420, tzinfo=)}, 'doc_as_upsert': True}, id=1)
```

Passing `doc` as the second argument should fix your issue:

```py
mock_client.update.assert_called_once_with(
            settings.ES_INDEX,
            'doc',  # Added
            id=q.id,
            body={
                'doc': {
                    '_type': 'doc',
                    'text':'{}\n{}'.format(question_title, question_body),
                    'question_body':question_body,
                    'title': question_title,
                    'id': q.id,
                    'created': q.created,
                },'doc_as_upsert': True,
            }
        )
```

Comment: Exactly, but I have put a ```'doc'``` parameter after ```settings.ES_INDEX``` and it did not work

Comment: AssertionError: ```Expected call: update('answerly', 'doc', body={'doc': {'_type': 'doc', 'text': 'Unit test\nsome
 long text', 'question_body': 'some long text', 'title': 'Unit test', 'id': 1, 'created': datetime.datetime(201
9, 9, 11, 20, 28, 43, 112222, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 'doc_as_upsert': True}, id=1)```
```Actual call: update('answerly', 'doc', body={'doc': {'text': 'Unit test\nsome long text', 'question_body': 'som
e long text', 'title': 'Unit test', 'id': 1, 'created': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 11, 20, 28, 43, 112222, tzin
fo=<UTC>)}, 'doc_as_upsert': True}, id=1)```

Comment: The `'_type': 'doc',` seems to be missing from the actual call now. Also, the expected question body is `some long text`, while the actual is `som e long text`. Not sure if you accidentally added a space there.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing out on something.. this is my upsert function in elasticsearch.py ```def upsert(question_model):
 client = get_client()
 question_dict = question_model.as_elasticsearch_dict()
 doc_type = question_dict['_type']
 del question_dict['_id']
 del question_dict['_type']
 response = client.update(
  settings.ES_INDEX,
  doc_type,
  id=question_model.id,
  body={
   'doc': question_dict,
   'doc_as_upsert': True,
  }

 )
 return response```

Comment: Now the test passes when I removed the ```del question_dict['_type']``` inside ```elasticsearch.py``` module. So your solution worked @Bob

Answer (score 0):

Add the `doc` parameter to your mock:

```
mock_client.update.assert_called_once_with(
            settings.ES_INDEX,
            id=q.id,
            doc='doc',
            body={
                'doc': {
                    '_type': 'doc',
                    'text':'{}\n{}'.format(question_title, question_body),
                    'question_body':question_body,
                    'title': question_title,
                    'id': q.id,
                    'created': q.created,
                },'doc_as_upsert': True,
            }
        )
```

Comment: This won't work because `'doc'` isn't passed as a keyword argument in the actual call. `'doc'` should just be passed as the second argument after `settings.ES_INDEX`.

Comment: @Bob, I tried what @2ps told me and it gave the same error. Also replacing ```doc='doc'``` by ```'doc'``` returns a syntax error:

Comment: Instead of  `(settings.ES_INDEX, id=q.id, doc='doc',...)`, it should be `(settings.ES_INDEX, 'doc', id=q.id,...)`, which shouldn't return a syntax error.